# How LibreOffice does make "Text" transparent? WRITABLE but TRANSPARENT

Tags: python, transparent

I downloaded Python and PySide (Qt) some days ago.

I was asking myself on howto clone **Text (from draw functions)** from LibreOffice.
You know, when you can type on transparent environnement but the characters still appears.

I would like to clone it in python, but obviously not the whole LibreOffice. Must make a GUI Application that is **invisible, but not the text**. (To maybe, in future, use it as a **reminder on the Windows Desktop**)
The reason is still mainly to **learn**.

I use Python 2.7.7 and Windows 7.

**Thanks** for the time you will pass on understanding my request and answering to it. For **any others details, let a comment here**.

Comment: By not painting where the text isn't.

Comment: And by which way it is possible in PyQt?