# Place on a determinated position of the screen : Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to display the app on a specific postion (regardless of the screen models).
I have at the moment

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

Thanks for answering and thanks for checking if you don't know either a way to do it or directly the answer for : [Writable but transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521869/how-libreoffice-does-make-text-transparent-writable-but-transparent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control placement of tk root window use geometry

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("+1120+110") # x and y coordinates on a screen
root.mainloop()
```